# Meteor accounts-facebook login Error in OAuth Server

Tags: facebook, oauth, meteor

since the latest meteor update (0.8.1.3) I cannot use accounts-facebook anymore. I setup the whole thing as I usually did but after getting redirected back from facebook to my meteor app I get the following Exception in my meteor log :

```
W20140528-15:12:02.762(2) (oauth_server.js:104) Error in OAuth Server while storing pending login result.
TypeError: Object function (document)
{
    _.extend(this, document);
    this.id = document._id;
} has no method 'Optional'
at Object.OAuth._storePendingCredential (packages/oauth/pending_credentials.js:45)
at middleware (packages/oauth/oauth_server.js:100)
at packages/oauth/oauth_server.js:62
```

Downgrading to an earlier version did not help. Did anybody noticed that error before?

Answer (score 1):

Hehe, I actually had a Pojo called "Match" (its a Soccer Bet Game) which was used by the corresponding collection to transform documents into a pojo.

Well, not a good idea to override a Meteor wide function with a pojo :) Now everything works fine again!